# Log all events on all tables with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, events, logging, triggers

I need to log all events on all tables in table database_log (id, user, timestamp, tablename, old_value, new_value).

I thought I can create the same trigger on all tables (~25) with a little php script dynamically replace the name's table. But in this case I can retrieve the old and new value, because all tables haven't the same columns so I can't just concat all field for store in the "old_value" and "new_value" (even if I retrieve fields in schema because I can't use a concat() on it for select all value and store in variable).

For exemple a :

```
 SELECT * into v_myvar FROM my_table where id=OLD.id;
 CALL addLog(v_myvar)
```

Where addLog is procedure taking my old value and add a line with other informations, could save my life.

So, I'm looking for a sexy solution with one trigger and/or one procedure (by table) or a useful tool. Someone have a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log';
```

The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients.

See the MySql [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)